# Location or path issues on PHP

Tags: php

Here is the directory structure I am using for my project:

```
assets
connection
    connection.php
controller
    Controller.php
include
    header.php
    footer.php
model
    Model.php
process
    add-data.php
view
    index.pp
    sales-form.php
    report.php
config.php
index.php
```

**First, its load the `index.php` file which contains this code:**

```
require_once("controller/Controller.php");
$controller = new Controller;
$controller->index();
```

**You see that it loads the `index()` method from the Controller.php file which code is below:**

```
public function index () {      
    require_once('view/index.php');
}
```

**Now `index.php` file container this code:**

```
<?php require_once("include/header.php"); ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="view/sales-form.php">Record a new sales</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="view/report.php">Search Report</a> 
<?php require_once("include/footer.php"); ?>
```

Now, you can see **Record a new sales** button link is this: **view/sales-form.php** but when I go to that link it's showing me that error message:

> Warning: require_once(config.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\job-tasks\include\header.php on line 1

**that sales-form.php file contains this code**

```
<?php require_once("../include/header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../include/footer.php"); ?>
```

**This header.php code this below:**

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
html code....
```

can you tell me how can I solve that link/location related issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `header.php` should be:

```
<?php require_once(__DIR__. '/../config.php'); ?>
```

since `config.php` is outside of the `include` folder so you need to move one step back (go to the root of your project) and then access it.

You should convert all your endpoints to use the root path which based on your project will lead to the Controller so:

***Controller.php:***

```
<?php 
// get the model class
require(__DIR__ .'/../model/Model.php');

// create Controller class
class Controller {

    // hold the model object
    public $model;

    public function __construct () {

        // create model object
        $this->model = new Model();
    }   

    public function index () {      
        require_once(__DIR__ .'/../view/index.php');
    }

    public function salesForm () {
        require_once(__DIR__ .'/../view/sales-form.php');
    }
}
```

***Header.php***

```
<?php require_once(__DIR__ .'/../config.php'); ?>
```

***Model.php***

```
require_once(__DIR__ .'/../config.php');
```

Comment: dong so it's showing me that error when loading the project first index.php page: `Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\job-tasks\include\header.php on line 1`

Comment: can you try `require_once __DIR__. '/config.php'`

Comment: `require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\job-tasks\include/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\job-tasks\include\header.php on line 1`

Comment: Can you switch from require_once to simple require?

Comment: same error. Is there any way? I mean can change folder structure in some way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195273/discussion-between-pr1nc3-and-creativeartbd).

Comment: Please check the link I have sent you.

Answer (score 0):

Before controller is called from controller.php file, you may have to include the config file as below:

```
<?php require_once('../config.php'); ?>
```

Comment: so then I don't need to add that config.php file to other file?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to add the config.php file in other file. Because controller is the main file which will allow the view to render it.